# Launch error caused by @react-navigation/bottom-tabs 5.x

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

After upgrading to latest @react-navigation/stack 5.2.10 from previous 5.x. The App (react native 0.61.5) launch has an error:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: C:\D\code\js\emps_fe615\node_modules\@react-navigation\bottom-tabs\src\index.tsx: Unexpected token (15:12)

  13 |  * Types
  14 |  */
> 15 | export type {
     |             ^
  16 |   BottomTabNavigationOptions,
  17 |   BottomTabNavigationProp,
  18 |   BottomTabBarProps,
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░ 75.5% (802/923)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2020:02:14:43 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░ 75.5% (802/923), failed.
```

Here is the part of `package.json`:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.6",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.10"
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
```

Is there anyone seeing the error after upgrade? Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nothing is working, and if you're using yarn, you can try it:

1. `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock`
2. `yarn cache clean`
3. `yarn`

If NPM:

1. `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.lock`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`

[Bonus] Start React Native cleaning the cache:

Vanilla RN: `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Expo: `expo start -c`

Answer (score 1):

This below steps will solve the issue.

```
npm install @babel/core@^7.9.0
npm install @babel/runtime@^7.9.2
npm cache clean --force
expo start -c
```

Answer (score 0):

your @react-navigation/native version is 5.1.5
Your navigators (stack and bottom-tabs) versions are not the same as @react-navigation/native version.
That's why this issue occurs. Make sure those packages are having same version.

Answer (score 0):

This tends to happen if `expo-cli` is globally installed. If it is, try this:

```
yarn global add @babel/core
```

Or its npm equivalent

```
npm install -g @babel/core
```

However, it's been brought to my attention that it's better to not have any global packages, so you'd have to `yarn global remove expo-cli` and add it to your project instead (`yarn add expo-cli`).